# gzip: stdout: File too large when running customized backup script

Tags: bash, shell

I've create a plain and siple backup script that only backs up certain files and folders.

```
tar -zcf $DIRECTORY/var.www.tar.gz /var/www
tar -zcf $DIRECTORY/development.tar.gz /development
tar -zcf $DIRECTORY/home.tar.gz /home
```

Now this script runs for about 30mins then gives me the following error

```
gzip: stdout: File too large
```

Any other solutions that I can use to backup my files using shell scripting or a way to solve this error? I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: You might try using a different file system type.

Comment: /development runs on NTFS. The rest on ext 4 and then backing up to ntfs

Comment: Older versions of Samba had a 2G file size limit, in case that's relevant.

Comment: dumb question: is $DIRECTORY inside /home? because if so you will definitely be hitting some limits no matter what you do, since your script will be stuck in an infinite loop attempting to append the file into itself.

Comment: $DIRECTORY contains the directory where the files need to be stored to and thats on a FLASH drive NTFS partitioned

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*File too large* is a error message from your libc: The output has exceeded the file size limit of your filesystem.

So this is not a *gzip* issue.

Options: Use another Filesystem or use split:

```
tar czf - www|split -b 1073741824 - www-backup.tar.
```

creates the backup.

Restore it from multiple parts:

```
cat www-backup.tar.*|gunzip -c |tar xvf -
```

Comment: He mentions that the filesystems are NTFS and EXT 4, so I'm not sure why libc would push back.  Nonetheless, sounds right so +1.

Answer (score 6):

Can the file system you are backing up to support large files?

Specifically, FAT32 has a limit of ~4GB in a single file, and other filesystems have similar limits.

If your backup is running for 30 minutes, the file could easily be getting that sort of size.

Comment: Likewise, do your versions of `tar` and `gzip` support large files?

Comment: He mentioned NTFS and ext4 in his response to WhirlWind's comment.

Answer (score -2):

Use a different compression utility, like compress or bzip2

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as gzip can handle large files just fine. It's a filesystem issue, and the error is from libc, not gzip.